# Wait command not acting as expected in Bash Script

Tags: bash, shell

I am making a script to play 4 different video feeds from 4 different camera DVRs via RTSP, and need them to be pretty much hands-free i.e. a dedicated mini pc running Debian that will, network connection permitting, always have the feeds playing without users needing to restart anything. My script below works as expected at first, but if I close one of the feeds or disconnect then reconnect the network connection, the next (and all the following) iterations of the `while` loop this happens:

1. feeds 1 through 4 connect correctly
2. `wmctrl` places windows correctly
3. All windows immediately close, and the loop continues as if the connection was lost.

I've tried removing the process numbers from the `wait` command as well as moving the function declaration outside of the loop (not sure what help that would do but tried nonetheless) but that changed nothing.

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
        -d)  debug=1    ;;
        *)    ;;
esac

close_all() {
    kill $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4
    return
}

source1="rtsp://user:password@10.0.20.30:554/streaming/channels/001"
source2="rtsp://user:password@10.0.20.33:1026/streaming/channels/001"
source3="rtsp://user:password@10.0.20.31:1024/streaming/channels/001"
source4="rtsp://user:password@10.0.20.34:1027/streaming/channels/001"

while true; do

    ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp -infbuf -stimeout 100 -autoexit -i $source1 -vf "scale=w=960:h=540" > /dev/null 2>&1 & p1=$!
    ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp -infbuf -stimeout 100 -autoexit -i $source2 -vf "scale=w=960:h=540" > /dev/null 2>&1 & p2=$!
    ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp -infbuf -stimeout 100 -autoexit -i $source3 -vf "scale=w=960:h=540" > /dev/null 2>&1 & p3=$!
    ffplay -rtsp_transport tcp -infbuf -stimeout 100 -autoexit -i $source4 -vf "scale=w=960:h=540" > /dev/null 2>&1 & p4=$!
    sleep 5

    window1=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$source1" | cut -d' ' -f 1 )
    window2=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$source2" | cut -d' ' -f 1 )
    window3=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$source3" | cut -d' ' -f 1 )
    window4=$(wmctrl -l | grep "$source4" | cut -d' ' -f 1 )

    wmctrl -i -r $window1 -e 0,0,0,960,540
    wmctrl -i -r $window2 -e 0,0,540,960,540
    wmctrl -i -r $window3 -e 0,960,0,960,540
    wmctrl -i -r $window4 -e 0,960,540,960,540

    [ "$debug" = 1 ] && echo " $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4"

    # Originally had wait -n $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4 here 
    wait -n

        #One of the ffplay commands exited so something must be wrong, 
        #close all and retry

    close_all

    echo "Connection interrupted, retrying..."
    echo "Or press q to exit..."
    read -t 3 -N 1 input
    case $input in
        q|Q) exit   ;;
        *)  ;;
    esac

        # Picking an arbitrary DVR to test for now.  
    until ping -q -c 1 10.0.20.30 > /dev/null 2>&1; do
        echo "Connection failed, will keep retrying in 3 seconds..."
        echo "Press q to abort."
        read -t 3 -N 1 input
        case $input in
            q|Q)    exit ;;
            *)  ;;
        esac
    done

done
```

I need it to behave like it does the first iteration and wait until something actually goes wrong. I assume it has something to do with the `wait` command and processes or job control or something but google searching has led me nowhere. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You'll probably want `close_all` to `wait`, otherwise you'll have a bunch of freshly killed processes being caught on the next iteration of the loop

Comment: Do you mean put `close_all` before of `wait`? Wouldn't that simply close the processes I am trying to wait on? Honestly I don't even know why I declared a function for a single command like that. I think because my initial intent was to make a trap to close everything, but even then it would still work without the function.

Comment: I mean to use `close_all() {
    kill $p1 $p2 $p3 $p4; wait;
    return;
}`